# Add a token I already have to MSAL token cache?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm writing something in which I'd like to use MSAL.NET to handle just caching and refreshing a token that I've gotten elsewhere, is that possible? The situation is that another component of the system I'm working on, which is not written in .NET and does not use MSAL, obtains the token and refresh token and passes them to my code, which *is* in .NET Core and where I'd like to use MSAL. Ideally, I'd like to just put those into an MSAL token cache and the proceed as if MSAL had acquired them for me. Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [custom token serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization#custom-serialization-for-windows-desktop-apps-and-web-appsweb-apis) for msal to control to token caching and acquisition behavior.

Comment: That seems possible, although that's more for storing and retrieving tokens that you got through MSAL. What I mean is, it seems like I could do it by creating something in MSAL's token serialization format and then registering a deserialization callback that  presents that to MSAL when it asks for it. But is that format documented? I wrote a quick program to get a token and serialize the cache to see what it looks like, and it contains a lot of other information besides the tokens. It looks like things that are probably derived from the tokens, but I'm not sure where it all comes from.

Comment: It seems like the token cache serialization isn't mean to be used in this way. It's problematic to do this AND real cache serialization. For instance, you could initially load the cache by creating a serializer that takes a serialized cache and then on the first call to the "before access" callback, returns that instead of getting it where your serializer normally would. But then there's no way to tell it to write it out to wherever you really serialize to (at least if you want to use the SuggestedCacheKey MSAL gives you, because you won't have it in the before access callback).

Comment: Kindly post the details at the MSAL library's (issues)[https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues] page. I'll try to get a dev interested.